# Delay a function in dojo widget from being called until global variable is set

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a custom pie chart being rendered from an external js file.  I use xhrget to get the data i need to populate the pie chart.  The url i am using includes a global variable but my problem is that the function in he script gets called before the global variable is set.

Here is my code:

```
    var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D(this.id,{fill:"transparent"});


        chart1.setTheme(dojox.charting.themes.MiamiNice,{fill:"transparent"});

        chart1.addPlot("default", {
        type: "Pie",
        labels: false,
         labelStyle: "rows",
        precision: -10,
        fontColor: "black",
        labelOffset: -20,
        radius: 150
      });

      console.log(this.getURLFunction(this.id ));

        chart1.theme.plotarea.fill = undefined;
        this.xhrDeferred = dojo.xhrGet({
            url: this.getURLFunction(this.id)**,//"../traffic-analysis/get-ip-dist/format/json/ds/1/data/rate/tTime/1334787567/fTime/1334182767/time/604800/drilldown/true/displayedTime/enabled?dojo.preventCache=1334787568120",

            sync: true,
            handleAs: "json",
            preventCache: true,
           load: function(responseObj) {


            var seriesData=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
            chart1.addSeries("IP", dojo.map(responseObj.pieItems, function(p){
  return {
    y:    p[1], // value
    text: p[0],  // label
    tooltip:p[0] +": " + p[1]
  };
}));

      var anim_a = new dojox.charting.action2d.MoveSlice(chart1, "default");
      var anim_b = new dojox.charting.action2d.Highlight(chart1, "default");
      var anim_c = new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(chart1, "default");
        chart1.render();

        var chartLegend = new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({
                chart: chart1,
                swatchSize: 12,
            },
            "chartLegend");

            },
            // error: function(error, args) { console.warn("error", error); }
            error: function(error, args) { 

                _this.xhrError = true;
                _this.chartStatusBar.innerHTML = chartErrorMsg(_this.id);
                console.log(error);
            }


        });
```

the getURLFunction(this.id) under the xhrget for url refers to an element in the html that has an id that calls a specific function from the html file.

that function is getURL_IpDist() and it returns the url that the xhrget will use to get the data which is /traffic-analysis/get-ip-dist/format/json" + sc.toURL();

sc is the global variable that I need to be set before my function tries to grab the url.  this is set in another external javascript file. 
Does anyone know how to delay dojo or javascript from loading before the variable is set?

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that the code you posted lives in a seperate js file and you are including it using a `<script>` tag.

Have you tried wrapping this code in a `ready` function?

```
require(["dojo/ready"], function(ready){
    ready(function(){

        // var chart1 = ...

    });
});
```

Doing this will not execute the code until the browser has parsed the entire dom.  Which should include the other code that sets the global variable.

Comment: i guess i forgot to specify that i am making a custom dojo widget. so wrapping that only gives me an error.  Also i am using an older version of dojo as that is what i am being required to use at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using variables, use functions.  The component that sets the "global variable" actually should invoke a function instead that sets the global variable in question.

Other parts of your application can then use dojo.connect() to connect to the function, so anytime it is called, dojo will call whatever handlers connected to the function.  For example:

```
global.setVar = function(value) {
  global.var = value;
}
...
dojo.connect(global, 'setVar', null, function() {
  alert("Global variable has been set to: "+global.var);
});
```

You can use dojo's subscribe/publish facility to get a similar capability, or possibly even your own dojo.Deferred instance.  Which method you employ to synchronize communication depends on how your application is designed and what your specific needs are.